# IronPython Array[byte] to string

Tags: ironpython

I'm trying to save received data into file:

```
#data Array[byte]

fl = open(file_name, 'wb')
fl.write(<.....>)
fl.close()
```

So how can I get string from Array[byte] to make it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IronPython 2.6 and above you should be able to do:

fl.write(bytes(<......>))